# How to create a hyperlink to an executable?

Tags: front-end, notebooks, hyperlink

I tried the following:

```
Hyperlink["label","file:C:\\Program Files\\ProgramName\\program.exe"]
```

But when I click the generated link the system freezes. For any other file, it opens inside Wolfram notebook. So I assume it's trying to open the executable in the notebook and freezes the front end.

What is the way to achieve this?

By the way `SystemOpen["file:C:\\Program Files\\ProgramName\\program.exe"]` works fine. But I need a hyperlink.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As an example, this opens up the editor:

```
Button[Hyperlink["Notepad"]
 , SystemOpen[File["C:/Program Files/Notepad++/notepad++.exe"]]
 , Appearance -> {"Frameless"}
 ]
```